# Sum contrast model intercept for multiple factors

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding, lm, contrasts

How is the intercept calculated for a linear model with multiple factors using `contr.sum`.  From what I've read the intercept is equal to the "grand mean", which as I can understand it is essentially the mean of the mean for each level.  However, when I try to calculate the grand mean for a simple example, it isn't equal to what is given by the model.

```
mymtcars <- mtcars
mymtcars$cyl <- factor(mymtcars$cyl)
mymtcars$gear <- factor(mymtcars$gear)

m.mymtcars <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + gear, data = mymtcars, contrasts = list(cyl = contr.sum, gear = contr.sum))
```

The model shows a "grand mean" of:

```
coef(m.mymtcars)[1]
(Intercept) 
   20.63659
```

The overall mean of the data is:

```
mean(mymtcars$mpg)
[1] 20.09062
```

When I try to calculate a mean of the level means I get:

```
library(dplyr)
cylAvg <- mymtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(levelAvg = mean(mpg))
gearAvg <- mymtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(levelAvg = mean(mpg))
mean(c(cylAvg$levelAvg, gearAvg$levelAvg))
[1] 20.58775
```

What is the correct way to calculate the intercept given by lm?

Answer (score 2):

You are using contr.sum where all levels are compared to the last level, and with the added constraint that all the coefficients (except the intercept) sum up to zero.

The grand only holds when the number of observations in each category is equal, for example:

```
set.seed(222)
z = rnorm(10)
data = data.frame(x=factor(rep(0:1,10)),
y=factor(rep(0:1,each=10)),z)

 mean(data$z)
[1] 0.1996044

table(data$x,data$y)

    0 1
  0 5 5
  1 5 5

lm(z ~ x+y, data = data, contrasts = list(x = contr.sum))$coefficients[1]

(Intercept) 
  0.1996044
```

Now we change the distribution, and you see the intercept is no longer the grand mean:

```
data = data.frame(x=factor(sample(0:1,10,replace=TRUE)),
y=factor(rep(0:1,10,replace=TRUE)),z)

table(data$x,data$y)

    0 1
  0 6 6
  1 4 4

lm(z ~ x+y, data = data, contrasts = list(x = contr.sum,y=contr.sum))$coefficients[1]

(Intercept) 
  0.3066638
```

And this can be derived as the mean of means of all cells / groups:

```
data %>% group_by(x,y) %>% summarize(mean=mean(z)) 
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   x [2]
  x     y       mean
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
1 0     0      0.152
2 0     1     -0.609
3 1     0      0.904
4 1     1      0.780

data %>% group_by(x,y) %>% summarize(mean=mean(z)) %>% pull(mean) %>% mean
[1] 0.3066638
```

For your dataset:

```
mymtcars %>% count(cyl,gear)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  cyl   gear      n
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 4     3         1
2 4     4         8
3 4     5         2
4 6     3         2
5 6     4         4
6 6     5         1
7 8     3        12
8 8     5         2
```

It is missing one level (cyl=8,gear=4), so not very good for doing contr.sum, if we repeat the above we get something close:

```
mymtcars %>% group_by(cyl,gear) %>% 
summarize(mean=mean(mpg)) %>% pull(mean) %>% mean
[1] 20.78438
```